# Minecraft forge mod version 1.7.10 crashes constantly after adding new recipes

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm currently having some issues developing my first hand-written mod. I am currently using Eclipse Photon as my IDE, am running Windows 10 Home on a 64 bit machine, and have 4 GB of ram.

Here is my code:

```
package com.haxium.basicmod.obsidian.armor;

import net.minecraft.init.Blocks;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraftforge.common.util.EnumHelper;
import net.minecraft.init.Items;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.item.Item.ToolMaterial;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemArmor.ArmorMaterial;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.event.FMLPreInitializationEvent;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry;
import com.haxium.basicmod.obsidian.armor.ItemObsidianGeneric;
import com.haxium.basicmod.obsidian.armor.ItemObsidianArmor;
@Mod(modid = ObsidianArmor.MODID, version = ObsidianArmor.VERSION, name = ObsidianArmor.NAME)
public class ObsidianArmor {
    public static final String MODID = "obsidian_armor";
    public static final String VERSION = "1.7.10-Stable-1.1.0.1";
    public static final String NAME = "HaxCraft Obsidian Edition";
    //tools
    public static Item obsidian_pickaxe;
    public static Item obsidian_sword;
    public static Item obsidian_ingot;
    ToolMaterial obsidian = EnumHelper.addToolMaterial("obsidian", 3, 4500, 10.1F, 4.5F, 10);
    //armor
    public static Item obsidian_helmet;
    public static Item obsidian_chest;
    public static Item obsidian_leggings;
    public static Item obsidian_boots;
    ArmorMaterial hardened_obsidian = EnumHelper.addArmorMaterial("hardened_obsidian", 20, new int[] {3, 7, 6, 3}, 25);
    @EventHandler
    public void preInit(FMLPreInitializationEvent event) {
        //tools
        obsidian_pickaxe = new ItemObsidianPickaxe(obsidian, "obsidian_pickaxe");
        obsidian_sword = new ItemObsidianSword(obsidian, "obsidian_sword");
        obsidian_ingot = new ItemObsidianGeneric("obsidian_ingot");
        GameRegistry.registerItem(obsidian_ingot, "Obsidian Ingot");
        GameRegistry.registerItem(obsidian_sword, "Obsidian Sword");
        GameRegistry.registerItem(obsidian_pickaxe, "Obsidian Pickaxe");
        //Armor
        obsidian_boots =  new ItemObsidianArmor(hardened_obsidian, 3, "obsidian_boots");
        obsidian_helmet = new ItemObsidianArmor(hardened_obsidian, 0, "obsidian_helmet");
        obsidian_chest = new ItemObsidianArmor(hardened_obsidian, 1, "obsidian_chest");
        obsidian_leggings = new ItemObsidianArmor(hardened_obsidian, 2, "obsidian_leggings");
        GameRegistry.registerItem(obsidian_helmet, "Obsidian Helmet");
        GameRegistry.registerItem(obsidian_chest, "Obsidian Chestplate");
        GameRegistry.registerItem(obsidian_leggings, "Obsidian Leggings");
        GameRegistry.registerItem(obsidian_boots, "Obsidian Boots");
    }
    @EventHandler
    public void init(FMLInitializationEvent event) {
        GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(Items.apple, 9),
                "XXX",
                "XXX",
                "XXX",
                'X', Blocks.leaves
        );
        GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(ObsidianArmor.obsidian_ingot, 9),
                "X",
                'X', Blocks.obsidian
        );
        GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(ObsidianArmor.obsidian_pickaxe),
                "ABC",
                "E",
                "H",
                'A', ObsidianArmor.obsidian_ingot, 'B', ObsidianArmor.obsidian_ingot, 'C', ObsidianArmor.obsidian_ingot,  'E', Items.stick, 'H', Items.stick
        );
        GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(ObsidianArmor.obsidian_sword),
                "B",
                "E",
                "HI",
                'B', ObsidianArmor.obsidian_ingot, 'E', ObsidianArmor.obsidian_ingot, 'H', Items.stick
        );
        GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(ObsidianArmor.obsidian_helmet),
                "ABC",
                "DF",
                'A', ObsidianArmor.obsidian_ingot, 'B', ObsidianArmor.obsidian_ingot, 'C', ObsidianArmor.obsidian_ingot, 'D', ObsidianArmor.obsidian_ingot, 'F', ObsidianArmor.obsidian_ingot
        );
        GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(ObsidianArmor.obsidian_chest),
                "AC",
                "DEF",
                "GHI",
                'A', ObsidianArmor.obsidian_ingot, 'C', ObsidianArmor.obsidian_ingot, 'D', ObsidianArmor.obsidian_ingot, 'E', ObsidianArmor.obsidian_ingot, 'F', ObsidianArmor.obsidian_ingot, 'G', ObsidianArmor.obsidian_ingot, 'H', ObsidianArmor.obsidian_ingot, 'I', ObsidianArmor.obsidian_ingot
        );
        GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(ObsidianArmor.obsidian_leggings),
                "ABC",
                "DF",
                "GI",
                'A', ObsidianArmor.obsidian_ingot, 'B', ObsidianArmor.obsidian_ingot, 'C', ObsidianArmor.obsidian_ingot, 'D', ObsidianArmor.obsidian_ingot, 'F', ObsidianArmor.obsidian_ingot, 'G', ObsidianArmor.obsidian_ingot, 'I', ObsidianArmor.obsidian_ingot
        );
        GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(ObsidianArmor.obsidian_boots),
                "AC",
                "DF",
                'A', ObsidianArmor.obsidian_ingot, "C", ObsidianArmor.obsidian_ingot, 'D', ObsidianArmor.obsidian_ingot, 'F', ObsidianArmor.obsidian_ingot
        );
    }
}
```

Any suggestions as to why this keeps failing? If needed, I do have a local copy of the crash log.

Comment: Here is the link to the crashlog: https://pastebin.com/tiy8qBMH

Comment: Which line is line 69?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shape of characters in your recipes need to be rectangles. If the recipes themselves aren't rectangles, add spaces where you don't need items. For example, this:

```
            "ABC",
            "E",
            "H",
```

should be this:

```
            "ABC",
            " E ",
            " H ",
```

Make that change in all of your recipes and the error will go away.

Answer (score 0):

At

```
GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(ObsidianArmor.obsidian_sword),
            "B",
            "E",
            "HI",
            'B', ObsidianArmor.obsidian_ingot, 'E', ObsidianArmor.obsidian_ingot, 'H', Items.stick
    );
```

You're lacking what `I` should be.

At the new code at line 69 you are missing a few spaces to make the re ipe square. You should always fill in a 3x3 grid. Or make sure each item in the array that defines the recipe contains an equal number of items.

```
 "B " // lacks a space
 "E ", // lacks a space
 "H  ", // proper amount of spaces
```

In those crash logs, always find the class that is your class that will give you the line number in your class that caused it

> com.haxium.basicmod.obsidian.armor.ObsidianArmor.init(ObsidianArmor.java:69)

This gives us line 69 in file ObsidianArmour.java

and the error at the top

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 7

Tells us that the problem lies in strings. There were too few characters instead of the expected 9.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your help. I will make those changes to the code

Comment: Joseph Sible, I made the appropriate changes and the code is still producing the same errors

Comment: Can you update the question with the new code and a link to a new crash log?

Comment: In those crash logs, always find the class that is your class `com.haxium.basicmod.obsidian.armor.ObsidianArmor.init(ObsidianArmor.java:69)` and the error at the top `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 7`

Comment: That is where I am starting to define some of the recipes to craft the items I have created in the mod. Why would it throw an IndexOutOfBounds exception when no index is being referenced?

Comment: Is it possible that I am using the method out of context and Forge just doesn't recognize the method call?

Comment: So, the grid definition was the index it was referring to. That is good to know. I've run the code again and noticed some more errors in my code, but I think your suggestions did the trick. Thanks again!

Comment: The game will now load, but crafting these items doesn't. Any ideas as to what I need to do to correct the problem?

Comment: @ConnorTozer that you need to ask in a new question

Comment: @Tschallacka Note that recipes do not HAVE to be 3x3. `"B","E","H"` is perfectly valid. They *do* have to be rectangular, though.

Comment: @Draco18s i know it is valid, ophad put spaces there so i just went with it.

Comment: @Draco18s Brainfart on my side, had the 9 total stuck in my head, typed that, meant 3x3. Fixed it now